# How do I access params in this hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

```
(rdb:569) @errors
#<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x104596758 @errors={}, @base=#<Deal id: nil, organization_id: nil, deal: "Free", value: nil, what: "this deal", description: "friday on sept. this deal", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, deal_image_file_name: nil, deal_image_content_type: nil, deal_image_file_size: nil, deal_image_uploaded_at: nil>>
```

For example, how would I call the `description` in `@errors` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@errors.instance_variable_get("@base").description